# Выбор хэш-функции для дерева

Tags: c, хеширование, бинарное-дерево

Имеется реализация хэш-таблицы на AVL-деревьях с целым ключом, где длина ключа (в таблице, а не в дереве) - не больше 256 байт. Для вычисления ключа в дереве использовалась CRC32. Этого хватало для работы с несколькими десятками тысяч элементов (до 10). Но есть мнение, что если речь идёт всего о сотнях элементов, то можно подобрать что-то пошустрей CRC32. Пока единственное, что при такой длине уверенно обгоняет CRC32 по скорости - ROT13... Но не в разы, на проценты. Или нет смысла возиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тут](https://www.strchr.com/hash_functions#results) проведено одно из самых обширных сравнений различных хэш-функций в плане производительности. Столбцы соответствуют различным наборам хешируемых данных, строки - функциям. Крупные числа показывают затраченное время (меньше - быстрее), рядом мелкие числа в квадратных скобках - количество коллизий (меньше - качественнее хеш).

Как видно из этого - большинство широко распространенных хеш-функций не так уж сильно различаются по скорости и производительности.

Comment: Ты одной ссылкой убил миллион размышлений на тему "как внутри устроены хэши" :-)